# Galois group of $x^{4}-4x^{2}+5$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Determine the Galois groups of the following polynomials over the fields
indicated:

(i) $x^{4}-4x^{2}+5$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Find the roots first.  Use the quadratic formula.

Comment: So, I got that the resolvant cubic is $x^3+4x^2-20x-80$, which has roots $-4, -2\sqrt{5}, 2\sqrt{5}$. But I don't know what $[K(-4,-2\sqrt{5},2\sqrt{5}) : K]$ is.

Comment: What does $ K $ denote?

Comment: $K$ is a field and $f \in K[x]$

Comment: Ok, just got that because it's over $\mathbb{Q}$, I'm supposed to be finding $[\mathbb{Q}(-4,-2\sqrt{5},2\sqrt{5}):\mathbb{Q}]$

Comment: @Tim That's $|\Bbb Q(\sqrt5):\Bbb Q|$.

Answer (score 1):

This can be decided by the discriminant $disc(f)$ and the cubic resolvent $R_3(f)$ of $f$, see K. Conrad's notes [Galois groups of cubics and quartics](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/cubicquartic.pdf), Theorem $3.6$ and following. Corollary $4.5$ shows how to find it for all irreducible quartics of the form 
$$
f(x)=x^4+bx^2+d.
$$
The possibilities are either $V_4,D_4$ or $C_4$.