# Galois group of $X^4-4X^2+5$ and $X^4-5X^2-5$

Tags: galois-theory

Some indications are given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2682709/galois-group-of-x4-4x25-over-mathbbq), but I have definitely not studied any relation of discriminants or resultants to Galois groups of cubics or quartics, so I think it could be done with Galois theory.

Does anyone have any indications? In principle one should compute their splitting fields explicitly, but in this case it's fairly hard so I guess there is another way.

Comment: At the link there is more given than just some indications. Why don't you try to read K. Conrad's [notes](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/cubicquartic.pdf)? It has all details you need for answering the question. And this is indeed Galois theory.

Comment: Both polynomials are biquadratic : this should help you...